# Cross domain source-maps (javascript)

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, source-maps

Let's take the following concrete example:

- A Javascript "kernel" providing some super nice service to third-part applications is "distributed" (as a JS bundle) at : http://myJSKernel.com
- domain-specific applications can download, configure and use the kernel's service from http://myJSKernel.com. Custom domains could be anything like: (http://consumer1.com, http://consumer2.org...)

On the basis of this scenario, while developing, I never execute the kernel alone, but I build smaller "domain-specific test applications" that are depend on and make use of the kernel.

The kernel being a JS "bundle" which is "babelified", "uglified", and "transfromed" in all the possible ways you can imagine, it is extremely hard to debug since the error messages do not point to the correct line numbers and so on...

Therefore I asked Webpack to also generate a source-map along with the kernel's bundle. So I have: "kernel.js" and "kernel.js.map", both available at http://myJSKernel.com

Now, I'm not sure about how the domain-specific applications (http://consumer1.com, http://consumer2.org...) can load the "kernel.js.map" when there is an error in the kernel ("kernel.js").

I hope my question is clear enough.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: The bit that isn't clear for me: _"how the domain-specific applications (http://consumer1.com, http://consumer2.org...) can load the "kernel.js.map" when there is an error in the kernel ("kernel.js")."_ What error are you talking about?

Comment: Well, kernel.js can be loaded, configure and executed until the point where an error occurs in the application flow. An error could be anything like trying to invoke a method on something "undefined". (while working on the kernel I sometimes do idiotic mistakes :p)

Comment: Of course if there is an error in the "domain-specific application", before loading the kernel, then, downloading the kernel will fail. But then, I do not care about the kernel.js.map since the error does not occur in the kernel